# Translate the Source File into SVF Format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-viewer

I would really like to test this viewer out - and I'm trying  to follow your guides on how to get the viewer up and running (using https://www.hurl.it/), but - I have encountered some problems.

I really don't understand this step: "Step 2: Upload a file to a storage location". (https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/)

They ask me to choose a name for my object. This can be the actual filename or something like a GUID generated by a data management system, but with a file extension.  The reason I don't understand this step is because the upload is not directed towards any specific file. It can be an actual file or not. They just want me to type in something and put on an extension? Like .rvt? How can the viewer then show a file that doesn't exist? It doesn't seem like it asks for to point to a file on my hard-drive? I entered "holmen1.rvt" and I ended up getting "status:failed" as I tried to verify that the translation job is complete (Step 3), calling the GET :urn/manifest. Result below:

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXlidWNrZXRmb3J0ZXN0aW5nOTUvaG9sbWVuMS5ydnQ",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
{
"name": "holmen1.rvt",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"messages": [
{
"type": "error",
"code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
"message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
},
{
"type": "error",
"message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
"code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
}
],
"outputType": "svf"
}
]
}
```

Anyone please help me understand this step!

Kind regards,

Torbjorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool (https://www.hurl.it/) you provided seems not to have a file input. I suggest you using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) instead. Here are my postman collection and environment for testing the Forge API (https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman).

After setting the postman environment up, you can navigate to `Data Managment API >> Data Mgmt - Upload a file`, and choose the Revit file you want to upload to the Forge, just like this:

[image]

Remember to set the `Filename` variable in the postman environment named `Autodesk Forge` in the above picture, and it's recommended to have the same name (with the file extension, rvt) in `step 4`.

Comment: Tanks a lot, Eason! I want to try to add some extensions to the model (one of these https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator). How would I move forward?

Comment: @Mykita Here is the path where the owner places extensions of the Forge RCDB project. (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic) It requires knowledge of the Weboack, Bable and ES2015+.

Comment: Here is another extension example repository (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions). It also requires knowledge of the Weboack, Bable and ES2015+.

Comment: If you didn't know how to write or load a viewer extension, you can refer this official tutorial from the Forge platform. (https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/extensions/)

Comment: Thanks! I did follow the official tutorials and I am getting a problem related to Token expiration. I have added:

    var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
        var accessToken = '<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>';
        var expireTimeSeconds = 86400;
        onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
    }
}
. But the viewer stops loading my model the minute the initial Access Token expires.    What could be the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it fetches a new access token before the current one expires